# Nvidia SLI not working only uses one GPU

Tags: nvidia

trying to get Nvidia SLI to work and having some difficulties.

(WW) VGA arbiter: cannot open kernel arbiter, no multi-card support

I have noticed this is the possibly first error relating to it, tried finding more info on this error but Not having any success. Latest upgraded version Ubuntu amd64, using Nvidia open source driver Ver 455.
snip of Xorg log,

```
(WW) VGA arbiter: cannot open kernel arbiter, no multi-card support
[     7.399] (**) NVIDIA(0): Depth 24, (--) framebuffer bpp 32
[     7.399] (==) NVIDIA(0): RGB weight 888
[     7.399] (==) NVIDIA(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[     7.399] (==) NVIDIA(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[     7.400] (**) NVIDIA(0): Option "Stereo" "0"
[     7.400] (**) NVIDIA(0): Option "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-1"
[     7.400] (**) NVIDIA(0): Option "SLI" "On"
[     7.400] (**) NVIDIA(0): Option "MultiGPU" "Off"
[     7.400] (**) NVIDIA(0): Option "BaseMosaic" "off"
[     7.400] (**) NVIDIA(0): Stereo disabled by request
[     7.400] (WW) NVIDIA(0): Invalid SLI option: 'On'; using single GPU rendering.
[     7.400] (**) NVIDIA(0): NVIDIA Multi-GPU disabled.
[     7.400] (**) NVIDIA(0): Option "MetaModes" "4096x2160 +0+0"
[     7.400] (**) NVIDIA(0): Enabling 2D acceleration
[     7.400] (II) Loading sub module "glxserver_nvidia"
[     7.400] (II) LoadModule: "glxserver_nvidia"
```

Anyone got it working that can spot a mistake in mine??

edit 6 Jan 11am
There was an update ready this morning I noticed when installing most of it was Nvidia related but still 455 and my driver info now has it labelled Proppriety, tested. It was labelled open source before update. Got all excited, rebooted after update and ran my Benchmarker...... Dissapiontment still only using one card.
I will add tho the performance from one card is way better than windows with a single card. I really look forward to the day this works.
I have re-added the log and config info as the formatting in the original paste has gone hay wire, it didnt look like that in the preview when I pressed post????

edit Jan 11 latest driver 460 updated, still no working SLI. Added nividia-bug-report.log as a link below.

xorg.log

```
[     7.356] (--) Log file renamed from "/home/hiy_po/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.pid-1720.log" to "/home/hiy_po/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log"
[     7.357] X.Org X Server 1.20.8 X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[     7.357] Build Operating System: Linux 4.15.0-124-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
[     7.357] Current Operating System: Linux Steam 5.4.0-58-generic #64~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Dec 9 17:11:11 UTC 2020 x86_64
[     7.357] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-58-generic root=UUID=7de58ac4-b64e-4c53-8827-12721a2aad2d ro nvidia-drm.modeset=1,quiet splash vt.handoff=1
[     7.357] Build Date: 30 November 2020  05:59:23PM
[     7.357] xorg-server-hwe-18.04 2:1.20.8-2ubuntu2.2~18.04.4 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
[     7.357] Current version of pixman: 0.34.0
[     7.357]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
to make sure that you have the latest version.
[     7.357] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
(++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
(WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[     7.357] (==) Log file: "/home/hiy_po/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log", Time: Thu Dec 24 00:21:14 2020
[     7.357] (==) Using config file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf"
[     7.357] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[     7.358] (==) ServerLayout "hiy_po SLI Configured0"
[     7.358] (**) |-->Screen "Screen0" (0)
[     7.358] (**) |   |-->Monitor "Monitor0"
[     7.358] (**) |   |-->Device "Device0"
[     7.358] (**) |   |-->GPUDevice "Device1"
[     7.358] (**) |-->Input Device "Keyboard0"
[     7.358] (**) |-->Input Device "Mouse0"
[     7.358] (**) Option "Xinerama" "0"
[     7.358] (==) Automatically adding devices
[     7.358] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[     7.358] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[     7.358] (==) Automatically binding GPU devices
[     7.358] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[     7.360] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[     7.360]    Entry deleted from font path.
[     7.360] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[     7.360]    Entry deleted from font path.
[     7.360] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[     7.360]    Entry deleted from font path.
[     7.360] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[     7.360]    Entry deleted from font path.
[     7.360] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[     7.360]    Entry deleted from font path.
[     7.360] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[     7.360]    Entry deleted from font path.
[     7.360] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[     7.360]    Entry deleted from font path.
[     7.360] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[     7.360]    Entry deleted from font path.
[     7.360] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[     7.360]    Entry deleted from font path.
[     7.360] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[     7.360]    Entry deleted from font path.
[     7.360] (**) FontPath set to:
/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
built-ins,
/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
built-ins
[     7.360] (**) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[     7.360] (WW) Hotplugging is on, devices using drivers 'kbd', 'mouse' or 'vmmouse' will be disabled.
[     7.360] (WW) Disabling Keyboard0
[     7.360] (WW) Disabling Mouse0
[     7.360] (II) Loader magic: 0x55ec3fda5020
[     7.360] (II) Module ABI versions:
[     7.360]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[     7.360]    X.Org Video Driver: 24.1
[     7.360]    X.Org XInput driver : 24.1
[     7.360]    X.Org Server Extension : 10.0
[     7.361] (++) using VT number 1

[     7.361] (II) systemd-logind: took control of session /org/freedesktop/login1/session/_31
[     7.362] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[     7.362] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/dri/card0 226:0 fd 12 paused 0
[     7.363] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card1)
[     7.363] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/dri/card1 226:1 fd 13 paused 0
[     7.365] (**) OutputClass "nvidia" ModulePath extended to "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nvidia/xorg,/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[     7.365] (**) OutputClass "nvidia" ModulePath extended to "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nvidia/xorg,/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nvidia/xorg,/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[     7.367] (--) PCI:*(15@0:0:0) 10de:1b81:3842:6276 rev 161, Mem @ 0xf6000000/16777216, 0xe0000000/268435456, 0xf0000000/33554432, I/O @ 0x0000e000/128, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[     7.367] (--) PCI: (16@0:0:0) 10de:1b81:3842:6276 rev 161, Mem @ 0xf4000000/16777216, 0xc0000000/268435456, 0xd0000000/33554432, I/O @ 0x0000d000/128, BIOS @ 0x????????/524288
[     7.367] (II) "glx" will be loaded. This was enabled by default and also specified in the config file.
[     7.367] (II) LoadModule: "dbe"
[     7.367] (II) Module "dbe" already built-in
[     7.367] (II) LoadModule: "extmod"
[     7.367] (II) Module "extmod" already built-in
[     7.367] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[     7.367] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[     7.370] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     7.370]    compiled for 1.20.8, module version = 1.0.0
[     7.370]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 10.0
[     7.370] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[     7.371] (II) Loading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nvidia/xorg/nvidia_drv.so
[     7.373] (II) Module nvidia: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[     7.373]    compiled for 1.6.99.901, module version = 1.0.0
[     7.373]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[     7.374] (II) NVIDIA dlloader X Driver  455.45.01  Thu Nov  5 23:01:05 UTC 2020
[     7.374] (II) NVIDIA Unified Driver for all Supported NVIDIA GPUs
[     7.374] xf86EnableIOPorts: failed to set IOPL for I/O (Operation not permitted)
[     7.374] (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 226:0
[     7.375] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
[     7.375] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[     7.375] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
[     7.375] (II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     7.375]    compiled for 1.20.8, module version = 1.0.0
[     7.375]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[     7.375] (II) Loading sub module "wfb"
[     7.375] (II) LoadModule: "wfb"
[     7.375] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libwfb.so
[     7.375] (II) Module wfb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     7.375]    compiled for 1.20.8, module version = 1.0.0
[     7.375]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[     7.375] (II) Loading sub module "ramdac"
[     7.375] (II) LoadModule: "ramdac"
[     7.375] (II) Module "ramdac" already built-in
[     7.377] (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 226:1
[     7.399] (WW) VGA arbiter: cannot open kernel arbiter, no multi-card support
[     7.399] (**) NVIDIA(0): Depth 24, (--) framebuffer bpp 32
[     7.399] (==) NVIDIA(0): RGB weight 888
[     7.399] (==) NVIDIA(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[     7.399] (==) NVIDIA(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[     7.400] (**) NVIDIA(0): Option "Stereo" "0"
[     7.400] (**) NVIDIA(0): Option "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-1"
[     7.400] (**) NVIDIA(0): Option "SLI" "On"
[     7.400] (**) NVIDIA(0): Option "MultiGPU" "Off"
[     7.400] (**) NVIDIA(0): Option "BaseMosaic" "off"
[     7.400] (**) NVIDIA(0): Stereo disabled by request
[     7.400] (WW) NVIDIA(0): Invalid SLI option: 'On'; using single GPU rendering.
[     7.400] (**) NVIDIA(0): NVIDIA Multi-GPU disabled.
[     7.400] (**) NVIDIA(0): Option "MetaModes" "4096x2160 +0+0"
[     7.400] (**) NVIDIA(0): Enabling 2D acceleration
[     7.400] (II) Loading sub module "glxserver_nvidia"
[     7.400] (II) LoadModule: "glxserver_nvidia"
[     7.400] (II) Loading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nvidia/xorg/libglxserver_nvidia.so
[     7.446] (II) Module glxserver_nvidia: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[     7.446]    compiled for 1.6.99.901, module version = 1.0.0
[     7.446]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[     7.446] (II) NVIDIA GLX Module  455.45.01  Thu Nov  5 22:58:18 UTC 2020
[     7.446] (II) NVIDIA: The X server supports PRIME Render Offload.
[     7.448] (--) NVIDIA(0): Valid display device(s) on GPU-0 at PCI:15:0:0
[     7.448] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-0
[     7.448] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-1 (boot)
[     7.448] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-2
[     7.448] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-3
[     7.448] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-4
[     7.448] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-5
[     7.448] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-6
[     7.448] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-7
[     7.448] (II) NVIDIA(0): NVIDIA GPU GeForce GTX 1070 (GP104-A) at PCI:15:0:0 (GPU-0)
[     7.448] (--) NVIDIA(0): Memory: 8388608 kBytes
[     7.448] (--) NVIDIA(0): VideoBIOS: 86.04.50.00.72
[     7.448] (II) NVIDIA(0): Detected PCI Express Link width: 16X
[     7.448] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: disconnected
[     7.448] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: Internal TMDS
[     7.448] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: 330.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[     7.448] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[     7.477] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): XXX Beyond TV (DFP-1): connected
[     7.477] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): XXX Beyond TV (DFP-1): Internal TMDS
[     7.477] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): XXX Beyond TV (DFP-1): 600.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[     7.477] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[     7.477] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: disconnected
[     7.477] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: Internal DisplayPort
[     7.477] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: 1440.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[     7.477] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[     7.477] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: disconnected
[     7.477] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: Internal TMDS
[     7.477] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[     7.477] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[     7.478] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: disconnected
[     7.478] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: Internal DisplayPort
[     7.478] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: 1440.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[     7.478] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[     7.478] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-5: disconnected
[     7.478] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-5: Internal TMDS
[     7.478] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-5: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[     7.478] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[     7.478] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-6: disconnected
[     7.478] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-6: Internal DisplayPort
[     7.478] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-6: 1440.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[     7.478] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[     7.478] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-7: disconnected
[     7.478] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-7: Internal TMDS
[     7.478] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-7: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[     7.478] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[     7.484] (II) NVIDIA(0): Validated MetaModes:
[     7.484] (II) NVIDIA(0):     "4096x2160+0+0"
[     7.484] (II) NVIDIA(0): Virtual screen size determined to be 4096 x 2160
[     7.492] (--) NVIDIA(0): DPI set to (85, 80); computed from "UseEdidDpi" X config
[     7.492] (--) NVIDIA(0):     option
[     7.492] (**) NVIDIA(G0): Depth 24, (--) framebuffer bpp 32
[     7.492] (==) NVIDIA(G0): RGB weight 888
[     7.492] (==) NVIDIA(G0): Default visual is TrueColor
[     7.492] (==) NVIDIA(G0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[     7.492] (**) NVIDIA(G0): Option "Stereo" "0"
[     7.492] (**) NVIDIA(G0): Option "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-1"
[     7.492] (**) NVIDIA(G0): Option "SLI" "On"
[     7.492] (**) NVIDIA(G0): Option "MultiGPU" "Off"
[     7.492] (**) NVIDIA(G0): Option "BaseMosaic" "off"
[     7.492] (**) NVIDIA(G0): Stereo disabled by request
[     7.492] (WW) NVIDIA(G0): Invalid SLI option: 'On'; using single GPU rendering.
[     7.492] (**) NVIDIA(G0): NVIDIA Multi-GPU disabled.
[     7.492] (**) NVIDIA(G0): Enabling 2D acceleration
[     7.492] (II) NVIDIA: The X server supports PRIME Render Offload.
[     7.494] (--) NVIDIA(0): Valid display device(s) on GPU-1 at PCI:16:0:0
[     7.494] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-0
[     7.494] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-1
[     7.494] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-2
[     7.494] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-3
[     7.494] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-4
[     7.494] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-5
[     7.494] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-6
[     7.494] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-7
[     7.495] (II) NVIDIA(G0): NVIDIA GPU GeForce GTX 1070 (GP104-A) at PCI:16:0:0 (GPU-1)
[     7.495] (--) NVIDIA(G0): Memory: 8388608 kBytes
[     7.495] (--) NVIDIA(G0): VideoBIOS: 86.04.50.00.72
[     7.495] (II) NVIDIA(G0): Detected PCI Express Link width: 16X
[     7.495] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-1): DFP-0: disconnected
[     7.495] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-1): DFP-0: Internal TMDS
[     7.495] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-1): DFP-0: 330.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[     7.495] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-1): 
[     7.495] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-1): DFP-1: disconnected
[     7.495] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-1): DFP-1: Internal TMDS
[     7.495] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-1): DFP-1: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[     7.495] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-1): 
[     7.495] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-1): DFP-2: disconnected
[     7.495] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-1): DFP-2: Internal DisplayPort
[     7.495] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-1): DFP-2: 1440.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[     7.495] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-1): 
[     7.495] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-1): DFP-3: disconnected
[     7.495] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-1): DFP-3: Internal TMDS
[     7.495] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-1): DFP-3: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[     7.495] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-1): 
[     7.495] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-1): DFP-4: disconnected
[     7.495] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-1): DFP-4: Internal DisplayPort
[     7.495] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-1): DFP-4: 1440.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[     7.495] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-1): 
[     7.495] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-1): DFP-5: disconnected
[     7.495] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-1): DFP-5: Internal TMDS
[     7.495] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-1): DFP-5: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[     7.495] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-1): 
[     7.495] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-1): DFP-6: disconnected
[     7.495] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-1): DFP-6: Internal DisplayPort
[     7.495] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-1): DFP-6: 1440.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[     7.495] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-1): 
[     7.495] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-1): DFP-7: disconnected
[     7.495] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-1): DFP-7: Internal TMDS
[     7.495] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-1): DFP-7: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[     7.495] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-1): 
[     7.495] (II) NVIDIA(G0): Validated MetaModes:
[     7.495] (II) NVIDIA(G0):     "NULL"
[     7.495] (II) NVIDIA(G0): Virtual screen size determined to be 640 x 480
[     7.495] (WW) NVIDIA(G0): Unable to get display device for DPI computation.
[     7.495] (==) NVIDIA(G0): DPI set to (75, 75); computed from built-in default
[     7.496] (WW) NVIDIA: Failed to bind sideband socket to
[     7.496] (WW) NVIDIA:     '/var/run/nvidia-xdriver-d8d7b980' Permission denied
[     7.496] (II) NVIDIA: Using 24576.00 MB of virtual memory for indirect memory
[     7.496] (II) NVIDIA:     access.
[     7.511] (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "4096x2160+0+0"
[     7.622] (==) NVIDIA(0): Disabling shared memory pixmaps
[     7.622] (==) NVIDIA(0): Backing store enabled
[     7.622] (==) NVIDIA(0): Silken mouse enabled
[     7.623] (**) NVIDIA(0): DPMS enabled
[     7.624] (II) Loading sub module "dri2"
[     7.624] (II) LoadModule: "dri2"
[     7.624] (II) Module "dri2" already built-in
[     7.624] (II) NVIDIA(0): [DRI2] Setup complete
[     7.624] (II) NVIDIA(0): [DRI2]   VDPAU driver: nvidia
[     7.639] (II) NVIDIA(G0): Setting mode "NULL"
[     7.644] (==) NVIDIA(G0): Disabling shared memory pixmaps
[     7.644] (==) NVIDIA(G0): Backing store enabled
[     7.644] (==) NVIDIA(G0): Silken mouse enabled
[     7.644] (**) NVIDIA(G0): DPMS enabled
[     7.644] (WW) NVIDIA(G0): Option "metamodes" is not used
[     7.644] (II) Loading sub module "dri2"
[     7.644] (II) LoadModule: "dri2"
[     7.644] (II) Module "dri2" already built-in
[     7.644] (II) NVIDIA(G0): [DRI2] Setup complete
[     7.644] (II) NVIDIA(G0): [DRI2]   VDPAU driver: nvidia
[     7.645] (II) Initializing extension Generic Event Extension
[     7.645] (II) Initializing extension SHAPE
[     7.645] (II) Initializing extension MIT-SHM
```

xorg.conf

```
# nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
# nvidia-settings:  version 440.82

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "hiy_po SLI Configured0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Files"
    ModulePath   "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi"
    FontPath     "built-ins"
EndSection

Section "Module"
    Load           "dbe"
    Load           "extmod"
    Load           "type1"
    Load           "freetype"
    Load           "glx"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5" 
#   Option         "Device" "/dev/input/mice"
#   Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5 6 7"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "XXX Beyond TV"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 80.0
    VertRefresh     50.0 - 75.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "Monitor1"
    VendorName   "Monitor Vendor"
    ModelName    "Monitor Model"
EndSection

Section "Device"
#   Identifier  "Card0"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 1070 FTW"
    BusID          "PCI:15:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
#   Identifier  "Card1"
    Identifier     "Device1"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 1070 FTW"
    BusID          "PCI:16:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-1"
    Option         "metamodes" "4096x2160 +0+0"
    Option         "SLI" "On"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
     SubSection     "Display"
         Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

[GPU0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mllFm.png)

[GPU1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKUat.png)

[Windows10 benchmark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Wq8F.jpg)

[nvidia-bug-report.log](https://1drv.ms/u/s!ArnaCoLUQ8Zrjwhwf25964uZDKze?e=7KEUDc)

Comment: Are the cards identical make/model?  Do you have SLI enabled in your motherboard BIOS?  Have you installed the SLI bridge?

Comment: @Nmath Are the cards identical make/model? Do you have SLI enabled in your motherboard BIOS? Have you installed the SLI bridge? –
 Yes cards are identical, bios is exactly the same in both cards, Yes it runs the SLI bridge. This is a working SLI setup under Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got an answer from Nvivdia Forums.

generix
Top Contributor
43m
From your log:

NVIDIA(0): Invalid SLI option: 'On'; using single GPU rendering
From nvidia driver changelog:

2020-09-17 version 455.23.04
* Removed support for the SLI modes "SFR", "AFR", and "AA".  SLI Mosaic,
Base Mosaic, GL_NV_gpu_multicast, and GLX_NV_multigpu_context are still
supported.
So there’s no real SLI auto-multi-gpu-rendering anymore wth Linux unless the application uses the mentioned gl methods.